# JSON RPC API id

Tags: json-rpc

I'm reading the [JSON RPC API documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) but I cannot understand what is the id that should be specified in the request (and that is also returned in the answer).

Is this simply a nonce that indicates that the given reply corresponds to a given request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is part of the JSON RPC specs:

http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification

> id
>   An identifier established by the Client that MUST contain a String, Number, or NULL value if included. If it is not included it is assumed to be a notification. The value SHOULD normally not be Null [1] and Numbers SHOULD NOT contain fractional parts [2]

It's basically an identifier for your client to know which response corresponds to which request - in case you're using something like a WebSocket endpoint, where you're getting a stream of replies instead of just one reply per request like HTTP POST.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Depending on how your application communicates with the API/node, this may help you to match queries to responses.